# React Native vertical text alignment when using explicit height

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I want to vertically center my text inside a view with an explicit height.

[Center text vertically in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57001704/center-text-vertically-in-react-native) did not fully answer my question because they don't use explicit height.

When I use

```
  <View style={styles.rightContainer}>

            <Text style={styles.label2}>
              Centered
            </Text>

        </View>
```

```
  rightContainer: {
    marginRight: 10,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
   label2: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
```

[image: result1]

If I take away the explicit height,

```
  label2: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
```

[image: it works]

it works.

I need to set the explicit height because I will convert this View to a tappable button.

How do I make this work?
What am I misunderstanding about react-native layout?

Comment: Cant you use `marginTop:height/2`?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the 'textAlignVertical' property is Android-only. Check the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text) on Text.

You could add an extra container wrapping the text:

```
export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
        <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Centered</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  rightContainer: {
    marginRight: 10,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  labelContainer: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  label2: {},
};
```